# Currently, the Spyder Project opens only one project at a time?

Tags: spyder

I have a question. Currently, the Spyder Project opens only one project at a time. Is there any future resource to open multiple projects simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder can't open several projects at the same time, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem. Hope this doesn't discourage you from using Spyder.